# Deserializacion de String Json Enum y Mapa en java

Tags: java, map, gson, enum, jackson

Poseo un string json que contiene el modelo de datos de ciertas variables contenidos en un mapa de tipo: 
LinkedHashMap
al realizar un cambio en el enum (agregar o modificar un item) la deserializacion deja de funcionar generando errores o cargando null en el key del mapa.
Como puedo hacer para que genere un objeto por defecto cuando ocurra este evento.
Utilizo Gson y Jacson para el proceso de deserealizacion y serealiacion.

Comment: Yo al menos no te entiendo. Edita la pregunta con una mejor explicación y añade algo de código para ver qué has hecho. También los errores.

Comment: Adicionalmente agrega el código que tienes que te esta fallando; puedes editar tu pregunta y agregarlo. Revisa [ask]